# How can I get the same number of bytes in Java vs a tad outdated Swift code?

Tags: java, swift

I am trying to get the same amount of bytes of the below snippet in `Java`. I am working with `decryption` of `encrypted` strings with known `key`. However, I am unable to reproduce these two lines of code in `Java`.

```
let usrKey: NSData! = (usrKey as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as NSData!
let keyBytes = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: usrData!.bytes)
```

1. How can I get the same `keyBytes` in `Java`?
2. What will the equivalent expression of the above in `Java` language?
3. What is the behavior of `mutating` ?

Java code I tried working with and the error below that.

```
byte [] keyBytes = userKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, newIvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
```

---

```
input 16 bytes
iv 16 bytes
key 32 bytes
ALGORITHM - AES128/CBC/PKCS5Padding
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:991)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
```

The issue is to find the right way to get the user key (could be short so padded) and create similar `32 bytes` (required by the decryption algo) between `Swift` and `Java` code.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Your Swift snippet does not have a clear relationship to the Java snipped.  Do `usrString` and `dataBytes` in Swift correspond to `usrKey` and `keyBytes` in the Java code?  It would be good if you showed all of the Swift code corresponding to the Java code you included.  The latter obviously does a lot more than the former.

Comment: @AnatoliP correct. However, there is not much of need for more Swift code. Although Java snip provides more info it can be changed since Swift code is in production and cannot change for now. So I just want to know how `keyBytes` turn out to be?

Answer (score 0):

The Java line

```
byte [] keyBytes = userKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

should have the same effect as the two Swift lines.  The problem is likely outside of the code that you showed in the question.  You may want to debug both Swift and Java code to make sure the `usrKey` matches `userKey` and that the resulting `keyBytes` are the same in both Swift and Java.

Please see Apple documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer/2427850-init for the meaning of `mutating`.  Also consult Apple documentation for any other API-related questions.